# Xamarin form: how to check if timer disposed?

Tags: xamarin

Timer _timer=new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, period, period);
I would like to check if _timer disposed or not in xamarin form plc ??
any help please

Comment: `if (_timer == null)`

Answer (score 0):

We can check with the token source if timer task cancelled:

```
        CancellationTokenSource TokenSource= new CancellationTokenSource();
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                //do something
                TokenSource.Cancel();

            }, TokenSource.Token);

             return !TokenSource.IsCancellationRequested;
        });
```